# Is there an alternative to the load command to import binary Tcl package

Tags: tcl, shared-libraries, tclsh

I am using a commercial tool interfaced with an homebrew tclsh(Synopsys EDA).

In their version, they removed the `load` command. Thus I cannot use third party libraries (Graphviz library in my case).

I wonder if there is a another way to import binary files (`.so` files)

Comment: What do you mean by having "removed the `load` command"? Have they removed (`rename ::load ""`) from the interpreter or are they building on a Tcl library configured with `--disable-load` autoconf flag?

Comment: What do you mean by "Graphviz library"? [Tcldot](http://wiki.tcl.tk/8634)? So, you want to do `package req tcldot`?

Comment: I do not know about that, but I guess that they disabled it when building the shell. I naively did `rename ::load load` and it returned me that the command `::load` does not exist

Comment: Yes, that is Tcldot that I want to use, but when I do `package require Tcldot`, it throws me a unknown command error for the `load` used in the associated `pkgIndex.tcl`. In which we can find the `ifneeded Tcldot " load [file join $dir tcldot.so] Tcldot"`

Comment: 1) pls report the output of `set tcl_patchLevel`.

Comment: 2) can you run: `interp create slave; slave eval {::load}`?

Comment: The patch level: 8.6.3. 
I tried the `interp` command and as it spawns a duplicate of the shell the load command is still unknown (I tried your command too and it still is the case)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168420/discussion-between-mrcalvin-and-krouitch).

Answer (score 1):

The only command in standard Tcl that brings in a dynamic library is `load`. (OK, `package require` can do too, but that's because it can call `load` inside.) Without that command, you only have options like *statically* linking your own code in and creating the commands in the `Tcl_AppInit` function, but that's really unlikely to work if you're already using someone else's code that's already done that sort of thing.

The easiest approach might be to run a normal `tclsh` as a subprocess via `exec tclsh script.tcl` (run and wait for termination) or `open |tclsh r+` (open pipeline). If they've not turned off those capabilities as well; you might be running in a safe interpreter where all those things are systematically disabled. I don't know of any way to break out of a standard safe interpreter (the mechanism for locking them down errs on the side of caution) so if that's the case, you'll just have to save the data you want to a file somewhere (by *any* mechanism that works; safe interpreters also can't touch the filesystem at all by default though that is often profiled back in in protected ways) and use a completely separate program to work with it.

Comment: If there is a hole that lets you do what you want, it is going to be application-specific (as safe interps let such holes be created by the controlling application even if they don't make them themselves; it's like how an OS can do things to hardware that user programs can't). That means you need to read the Synopsis EDA documentation very carefully.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if I have a process running on my machine, is there a way to load my own library (through debugging that process, injecting my package into it, and call MyPkg_Init with the Interp* that I somehow discover?)

Comment: You can load packages into interpreters other than the current one. (It's one of the optional arguments to `load`.) But there isn't a way to instruct a standard tclsh to do load anything that isn't allowed for in the script it is running. If the script uses `comm` or `dde` (or has `send` enabled in Tk) to let you talk to a master interpreter with access to `load`, you can do what you want easily. Otherwise… I guess you could use a C debugger to call `Tcl_Eval`? (`Tcl_FSLoadFile` exists, but doesn't have a pleasant API to use from a debugger.)